# .ReadLine() Error, Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, arduino

I have a code which stores data from serial port to an Array. But there is a sort of a problem I've ran into. Code that i'm using gives me an error when I Close the serial port or just when it runs more than about 20 seconds, then Visual Basic writes "The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request." Here is the Code. So maybe someone can help:

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        Dim i As Long
        i = 0
        While SerialPort1.IsOpen = True
            Do While i < 29
                incoming(i) = SerialPort1.ReadLine
                i = i + 1
            Loop
        End While

    End Sub
```

Comment: 29 is an unlucky number.  Start by *not* looping inside the event handler, move the "i" variable outside of the method and only read a single line at a time.  So you don't pull the rug with Close() while the loop is looping.  If you want to keep what you have (don't) then you need Try/Catch to catch the exception you get from the Close() call.

Comment: try to place `While SerialPort1.IsOpen = True` loop inside the `Do While` loop.

Comment: No, it didn't work...